# IBM Mobile first JSONstore is not working 7.1 version

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

My mobile first studio plugin version is **7.1.0.00-20161006-0540**. We have upgraded to the latest **iFix IMF 00-20161118-2214** for server.

We just started with the sample code provided in IBM knowledge center for JSONstore, but we got error **-11 OPERATION_FAILED_ON_SPECIFIC_DOCUMENT**

We called the JSONStore Initialization using JavaScript from WLinit Then only we will get this error -11, if it is in outside of Wlinit it's not showing anything in console.

We already mentioned JSONSTORE in application descriptor file

Comment: Above mentioned iFix is for server side. 
My mobile first studio plugin  version is 7.1.0.00-20161006-0540.
is there any iFix require for studio plugin?

Comment: It is always advised to update both the server and Studio (and rebuild the app). Please try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find the problem.
Issue was in config.xml

**Feature tag name was wrong here. I replaced StoragePluginStoragePlugin to StoragePlugin.**

**In new iFix also having the same problem.**

*Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

Calling JSONStore from WLInit (in initOptions.js?) is not a place to do the initialize for JSONStore...

You should initialize a JSONStore collection in your main.js, inside `function wlCommonInit()`, like so:

```
 function wlCommonInit() {
     var collections = {
         people : {
              searchFields: {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}
         }
     };

     WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function (collections) {
         // handle success - collection.people (people's collection)
         alert("success);
     }).fail(function (error) {
         // handle failure
         alert ("failure");
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
Still I have the same issue. I followed the above step.
I'm taking build from android studio. There I got a build error in gradle. To avoid that error, I had use                            



android {
       packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}
                                                                                  

is there any issue for this excluding
. (This error I got only when adding JSON store in my application descriptor.)

Comment: Try downloading the latest 7.1 studio iFix from IBM Fix Central and try again in a new project.

Comment: Can you provide your project that recreates this issue?

Comment: Its working in a click event. 
But onload initialization is not possible